# Como calcular o crc16 de uma string utilizando c#

Tags: php, c#, checksum

Olá, Preciso calcular o crc16 (checkSum) de uma string que contem letras e números ,eu consigo fazer essa operação com uma biblioteca nativa ? eu tenho um exemplo em php
'''

```
  private function getCRC16($payload) {
  //ADICIONA DADOS GERAIS NO PAYLOAD
  $payload .= self::ID_CRC16.'04';

  //DADOS DEFINIDOS PELO BACEN
  $polinomio = 0x1021;
  $resultado = 0xFFFF;

  //CHECKSUM
  if (($length = strlen($payload)) > 0) {
      for ($offset = 0; $offset < $length; $offset++) {
          $resultado ^= (ord($payload[$offset]) << 8);
          for ($bitwise = 0; $bitwise < 8; $bitwise++) {
              if (($resultado <<= 1) & 0x10000) $resultado ^= $polinomio;
              $resultado &= 0xFFFF;
          }
      }
  }

  //RETORNA CÓDIGO CRC16 DE 4 CARACTERES
  return self::ID_CRC16.'04'.strtoupper(dechex($resultado));
```

'''

Como ficaria esse método usando c# ?

Comment: mesma questão em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860356/how-to-generate-a-crc-16-from-c-sharp, e eu passaria o polinomio como um parametro, dependendo de onde você vai usar, diferentes padrões usam diferentes polinomios, e uma curiosidade aleatoria: o x86 tem um pacote de instruçõs adicionas, o SSE4.2, com uma instrução embutida de CRC32.

Comment: Ola anon , muito obrigado vou dar uma olhada, estou usando para criar um hash de validação do payload de pix (copia e cola)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvi o problema usando o projeto NullFX,que tem no repositório nuget, o metodo ficou da seguinte forma

```
public string GetHashCrc16(string input)
    {
        var convertBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        var crc16 = NullFX.CRC.Crc16.ComputeChecksum(Crc16Algorithm.CcittInitialValue0xFFFF, convertBytes);
        return crc16.ToString("X2");
    }
```

ficou bem pratico, abraços

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).